In which textbook can I find the proof for a theorem about the covering action of a group over its Cayley graph?
I'm trying to find a textbook which covers the following theorem I found in a paper:
Let $X$ be the Cayley graph of a group $G$ with respect to generating
set $S$. Then $G$ has a covering space action on $X$ such that $X/G$ is the wedge sum
of $|S|$ circles.
I can't find this result in Hatcher, and every other algebraic topology textbook I found doesn't cover graphs. I also consulted a few books on geometric group theory but didn't find this result. Is there any book you can think of where I can find such theorem?

I think you'd be better off trying to prove this yourself: Consider the the action of $G$ on $X$ induced by left multiplication and ponder what the quotient looks like.

I actually proved it myself, but unfortunately I need a textbook reference for my paper...

You could always cite the paper where you found it

Depending on the level of the paper one is writing, it could be fine to say say something along the lines of This is an exercise in covering space theory. That's what one would say in a research paper, anyway, or even in lecture notes aimed at a graduate class.
